# iOS VoIP App - Bringing a UIViewController to Screen When a Notification Is Received While App Is Terminated

Tags: ios, iphone, voip, pushkit

I am developing a VoIP app on iOS using PushKit.

When a user receives a PushKit Notification, the method `- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload` is called. And this method wakes up the app to handle the incoming connection.

My question is how can I bring a `UIViewController` to the screen so that the user decides to accept or reject the call?

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe that you can; you can post a local notification and make a sound but you can't launch your UI

Comment: How does Whatsapp, Viber and these guys do it?

Comment: I believe they just post a UILocalNotification with action buttons